# "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate" since Version 2210 October 27 update

Tags: resources

Since the version 2210: October 27 update every action brings up the "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate..." warning.

It is happening on all the machines in our office and multiple files (all copies of the same file made over many months/years)

The workbook is very complicated with a custom ribbon, pages and pages of code.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

I have tried the adjusting the number of calculation threads, clearing the cache and various other solutions offered by google.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
There was an error (missing reference to a date) which was in a hidden cell on a sheet referenced to the sheet which was showing the error.

This did not cause an error before the update.

However. The error was mine.

Thank you to all who contribute to this site. I have learned soo much through searching the posts and answers and have never needed to generate a question.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and so did a few of my colleagues. After the 2210 update, some of our more formula-heavy spreadsheets started showing that "excel ran out of resources..." message. I was able to solve it by rolling back the excel update to 2209.